# Как подключиться к lolachost с портом не по умолчанию?

Tags: asp.net, .net, mysql

**Добрый день.**

Подключаюсь  к MySQL  с ASP:

```
string connectionString = "data source=localhost; user id=root; password=1; database=leoasp";
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connectionString);
```

У меня стоит MySQL 4.1 на localhost (порт по умолчанию 3306 оставил), а MySQL 6 поставил на localhostc с портом 3308.

**Как мне подключиться к порту 3308?**

Я пробую localhost:3308, но получаю ошибку "u*nable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts*", а к 4.1. по net-connector не способен подключаться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта ссылка не поможет?

http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql

Попробуйте указать

> Port=3306;

Comment: Спасибо, Чад!
Надо было первым делом туда залезть, а не в гугл.
Обленился маленько я(
  :)